# Conditional SQL statement - conditioning on column to be returned

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I'm trying to make a conditional select statement, and the parameter I'm conditioning on is the column I want to return. Meaning - if something about a column in a table is true, I want to return that column; if not, I want to return the other column.

Ex:

```
IF table.obj_param_A = ?
BEGIN
SELECT obj_param_A FROM table
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT obj_param_B FROM table
END
```

I know this doesn't work, but it's the general idea of what I want. Any idea how to structure this properly?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not concern the column name returned, you can use `CASE`

```
SELECT 
    CASE  
        WHEN obj_param_A = ? THEN obj_param_A 
        ELSE obj_param_B 
    END AS value 
FROM table
```

Comment: What is value in this case?

Comment: Value is the name of the resulting column

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how you can use the table information about a specific column in order to select from specific columns.

```
Drop Table dbo.Test
Create Table dbo.Test (iVersion int, iVersion2 smallmoney)
Insert Into dbo.Test 
Select 1, 1.12

Declare @Test as nvarchar(200)
Select @Test = Column_Name  from information_schema.columns where Table_Schema = 'dbo' and table_name = 'test' and Ordinal_Position = 1

--IF (@Test = 'iVersion') --Equal To iVersion
IF (@Test != 'iVersion') ---Not Equal To iVersion
BEGIN
SELECT iVersion FROM dbo.Test
END
ELSE
BEGIN
SELECT iVersion2 FROM dbo.Test
END
```

This should return the data from iVersion2 since the Name of the First column is "iVersion" and the If Statement returns iVersion only if it is not the first column